# Gzip the file in unix more than 2 days

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I would like to do gzip the files which is older than 2 days where i have 3 directories, from that directories i need to zip the *log,*err,*out files using unix script can anyone help me.

Comment: Give the manpage for `find` a good read-through.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
#!/bin/bash

GREEN="\e[32m"
ENDCOLOR="\e[0m"

cd dir
gzip -c *.log > logs.gz
gzip -c *.err > err.gz
gzip -c *.out > out.gz

echo -e "${GREEN}Done${ENDCOLOR}"
```